# Flutter firebase OTP auto verification not working

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

WE are migrating an android app to flutter. We have implemented firebase based otp verification. In android, everything works perfectly. The user login and OTP verification works smoothly and the auto verification works fine

However, in flutter, the OTP auto verification does not work. The onVerificationCompleted does not get called when the user received an SMS.

Can someone give a clue on how to enforce the auto verification when an SMS is received?

```
auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: user_phone,
      timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        var sms_code = credential.smsCode.toString();
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        var verification_failed_msg = e.message;
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
        verificationID = verificationId;
        // _controller.resume;
        // setState(() {});
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
        print("SmsReadTimeout");
      },
    );
```

Comment: Anything in logcat, `verificationFailed`?

Comment: there is nothing in the logcat. The function never gets called.

Comment: If we put the code manually, then it succeeds. However, the SMS is not auto verified and the above code snippet which auto verifies never gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem and solution for it. Basically, the google recaptcha was preventing the auto verification of the SMS code. As soon as we removed the google auto recaptcha, the app started verifying the code.

There is a separate topic on how to remove google recaptcha from firebase otp verification